# "This site can’t be reached" shows when i type my vps ip in browser

Tags: ovh

I have bought a vps with debian linux operating system. I have webmin installed. my vps ip is '192.99.42.109'. when i type my ip in the browser address bar and press enter, it says 'this site can't be reached'. I have checked, apache is installed.

I have checked apache and webmin/virtualmin is installed. I have  created a virtual host using virtualmin.

it should show up apache2 page. but, its not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because of firewall blocking the port number 80 and 445. below is the command to release the block over port 80.

sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT